# AWS SAM - Extra policy is attached to Lambda's execution role for SQS event

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

A SQS triggered Lambda is configured like this in a SAM template:

```
MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: ....
      CodeUri: ....
      Policies:
      - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess
      - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - SQSPollerPolicy:
          QueueName: !GetAtt MyQueue.QueueName
      Events:
        TheSQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
```

I'm expecting this to create an execution role to which only 3 policies are attached. However, when created, the role also has the `AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole` attached to it.

How do I prevent this extra policy from being attached? It's undesirable since, for example, it grants `sqs:DeleteMessage` to all resources (`"Resource": "*"`).

**Update**

This seems like a bug to me (since it violates the principal of least privilege). AWS team, on the other hand, stated that this is expected and they might introduce a feature to address it (https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/2118).

Comment: If you find no way to remove the default role, you could add an explicit deny for sqs:DeleteMessage in one of your custom roles.

Comment: How would that look like since I still need the "DeleteMessage" for a specific queue?

Comment: You can always add an additional IAM role or SAM policy to the policies of the AWS::Serverless::Function granting additional permissions.